# Using ngForm in html form but getting error

Tags: html, angular

I have created an component called login and created a html form login.component.html then I wanted to make this form as Angular form. So I added `<form #loginform="ngForm">` in login.component.html and import

```
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms'
```

in login.component.ts. Can you help me where is the issue? I already tried

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
```

but still not working.

So when I run the server I get an error said:

```
  ERROR in src/app/login/login.component.html:2:23 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.
    
    2     <form #loginform="ngForm">
                            ~~~~~~
    
      src/app/login/login.component.ts:6:16
        6   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component LoginComponent.
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

login.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <form #loginform="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Remove `import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';` and include `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` in your nearest module file

Comment: I imported import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; in login.component.ts but still getting the same error

Comment: Have you also added that to the imports array in your module? Can you add a http://stackblitz.com to reproduce you issue?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/ehsanhosseini/angularform  Please check this

Comment: Fixed version, https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-kyfup6 . I added `FormsModule` in an imports array

Answer (score 0):

Use - import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'
in module.ts